# Is it possible to have ToDo items to be outside of code?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

Working on multi person project, I cant just add comments for todo items into code, which I do not want to check into TFS, however I like to keep my notes to myself and not pollute the source code for everyone else. Is there a way to keep my ToDo list separate from the source code?

Is there an extension that can point to a specific line, source file, but keeps it's items in a separate location than in the source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see only one way ：

Save your local files （with comments for todo items into code） to a different directory and undo your pending changes.

Do your changes again(without your own ToDo list), and check in the file into TFS.